# How to use CanBreak and CanPlaceOn in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I don’t know how these work. I want a iron shovel that can break dirt and grass and planks that can be placed on dirt. How would I do this. Are the commands different on pocket edition? Because I looked it up and tried but they didn’t work.

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:[minecraft:dirt, minecraft:gravel, minecraft:soulsand]} 

/give @p minecraft:gravel 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]}
```

Comment: Post the commands you used, and we can potentially identify what went wrong, or what you might be missing

Comment: /give @p minecraft:stone_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:[minecraft:dirt, minecraft:gravel, minecraft:soulsand]} (I don’t need soul sand) and /give @p minecraft:gravel 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]}. That’s not what I wanted though I just tried to see if I could get the hang of it and they didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

### important note: 
I haven't tested this yet

According to [the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give), the final part in the syntax of the give command is the Following:

> *components: json* (optional)‌[*Bedrock Edition only*]
>  
> Like DataTags but only supports `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` functions (for example,
> `/give @p iron_shovel 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass"]}}`)

so to fix your command, make it like this: (*Changes are marked with a **Boldened** word*)

/give @p **stone_shovel** 1 0 **{"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass, dirt, soulsand"]}}**

And the second one:

give @p **gravel** 1 0 **{"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["stonebrick"]}}**

### **EXPLANATION:**

the reason why your command didn't work is

1. it uses the old `minecraft:dirt` item ids, which doesn't work on the bedrock edition of Minecraft because it uses a different id system
2. it immediately said  `0 {>>>CanPlaceOn<<<:["m` instead of `0 {">>>minecraft:can_place_on<<<":{"` which doesn't work because it's incorrect syntax

Comment: OK funny story, it doesn’t. I tried the shovel one and it told me “can destroy” could not be updated.